# How can I delete HTML table td depending on the value of colspan attribute?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a Java Web Application project. I'm stuck on a problem where I would like to delete exactly 2 table cells when `colspan="3" or colspan > 1`using JavaScript.

Here is my code: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kaziali/bor6kmhf/16/)

It looks like this:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qCfC.png)

But I want it to look like this because using `colspan` messed this up:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KV5ou.png)

I've used this Javascript code which I've found online, but this only deletes the cells which have `colspan=3 or colspan>1` not the ones next to it.

```js
var countColumns = function(table) {
  if (!table || !table.tagName || table.tagName != 'TABLE') {
    throw new Error("The parameter 'table' must be a <table> DOM element.");
  }

  var maxColumnsCount = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
    maxColumnsCount = Math.max(table.rows[i].cells.length, maxColumnsCount);
  }

  return maxColumnsCount;
};

var table = document.getElementById('routine_table');
var rows = table.rows;

for (var i = (countColumns(table) - 1); i >= 1; i--) {
  var str = '';
  var cellToDelete = [];
  if (rows[1].cells[i] != undefined) {
    str = rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML;
    cellToDelete.push(i);
  } else if (rows[1].cells[i + 1].colSpan > 1) {
    str = rows[1].cells[i + 1].innerHTML;
    cellToDelete.push(i + 1);
    cellToDelete.push(i);
  }


  for (var j = 0; j < rows.length; j++) {
    for (var k = 0; k < 2; k++) {
      if (rows[j].cells[cellToDelete[k]] != undefined) {
        if (rows[j].cells[cellToDelete[k]].colSpan > 1)
          rows[j].deleteCell(cellToDelete[k]);

      }
    }
  }

}
```

```css
.table td {
  text-align: center;
}

.table th {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="routine_table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th>8.00 - 8.50</th>
          <th>8.50 - 9.40</th>
          <th>9.40 - 10.30</th>
          <th>10.30 - 11.20</th>
          <th>11.20 - 12.10</th>
          <th>12.10 - 1.00</th>
          <th>1.00 - 1.50</th>
          <th>1.50 - 2.40</th>
          <th>2.40 - 3.30</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>Saturday</th>
          <td> </td>
          <td> </td>
          <td> </td>
          <td colspan="3"> CSE 4214 </td>
          <td> I want to delete this cell when colspan=3</td>
          <td> I want to delete this cell when colspan=3</td>
          <td>CSE 4255 </td>
          <td> CSE 4213</td>
          <td> CSE 4213 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Sunday</th>
          <td> </td>
          <td> </td>
          <td> </td>
          <td> </td>
          <td> </td>
          <td> </td>
          <td> CSE 4213 </td>
          <td> CSE 4227 </td>
          <td> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Monday</th>
          <td> </td>
          <td> </td>
          <td> </td>
          <td> </td>
          <td> </td>
          <td> CSE 4255</td>
          <td> CSE 4255</td>
          <td> CSE 4203 </td>
          <td> CSE 4225</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Tuesday</th>
          <td> </td>
          <td> </td>
          <td> </td>
          <td> CSE 4203</td>
          <td> CSE 4227</td>
          <td> CSE 4225</td>
          <td colspan="3"> CSE 4228 </td>
          <td> I want to delete this cell when colspan=3</td>
          <td> I want to delete this cell when colspan=3 </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

It creates this output: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGZAy.png)

How can I solve this? A complete solution would be much appreciated.

Comment: use `queryselector('td[colspan=3]')` and `nextElementSibling`  property to access the next element.

Comment: @ajitkumar's solution will work, but please also consider if this is actually what you want to do. It seems like a kind of hack that will come back to bite you later. Is there any condition that determines that the colspan will be 3? Could you filter by that instead, ideally already in your java backend?

Comment: sorry in my first comment it is `querySelector` not `queryselector`.

Comment: Are you generating the td elements through script or writing manually? If you are rendering the HTML for the table through script then you can use some script while appending td to the table. So give clear idea regarding rendering of the table then I can suggest some solution for that.

Comment: the value of `colspan` is being generated with Java in the Backend. Also the I'm writing the  td elements manually. I just want to make a script which will check if the generated `colspan=3` or not. If `colspan=3` or `colspan>1` then It will delete 2 consecutive cells but not the cell having `colspan=3` or `colspan>1` @ManikantaChinta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the javascript code I've written to remove the extra td elements from HTML which you have given in the demo.

```
var table = document.getElementById('routine_table');
var rows = table.rows;
for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var cells = rows[i].cells;
    for (var j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) {
        var colspan = cells[j].colSpan;
        if(colspan != undefined && colspan != 1){
            for (let index = 0; index < colspan-1; index++) {
                rows[i].removeChild(cells[j+1]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This solution will works as per your problem statement(As I've tested in my local). But my question if you are writing colspan manually in the HTML then why don't you remove extra td elements as well. If not please share how are appending that colspan dynamically then I can update the above code as per your requirement.

Comment: Thanks a lot! @ManikantaChinta. It works perfectly for my code. Actually, I'm writing `colspan` manually with html but it's value is changing dynamically on the backend. The value is coming from the database actually. As it's a class routine, so slot size could change randomly according to that value. But that would be either 1 or 3 thats all I knew. That's why I couldn't remove extra td elements, because I wouldn't which slot will have what value(It could have been either 1 or 3).